# Unable to start mqtt image with password file

Tags: docker, mqtt, mosquitto

I have created a docker image of mqtt broker along with a config file. When I am trying to launch the image I am getting error saying: **Error: Invalid password hash for user user.**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM eclipse-mosquitto:1.4.12
RUN mkdir -p /mosquitto/data/
COPY mosquitto.conf /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf
COPY password.txt /mosquitto/config/password.txt
VOLUME /mosquitto/data/
EXPOSE 80
```

mosquitto config file:

```
## Logging

log_dest stdout
log_type error
log_type warning
log_type notice
log_type information


# per_listener_settings true
allow_anonymous false
password_file /mosquitto/config/password.txt
## MQTT Listener

listener 1883
protocol mqtt

## WebSockets Listener

listener 80
protocol websockets

## Persistence

persistence false
```

Password File:
[image]

Error:
[image]

I am trying to build an mqtt image with password file and websocket protocol

Comment: Edit the question to show how you created the password file.

Comment: Also please do not post images of text, post the actual text and format it. Images are hard to read or search and impossible for those that use screen readers.

Comment: Have you created the password file with the [Mosquitto password utility][1]? If not, perhaps give it a try.


  [1]: https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_passwd-1.html

Comment: Any particular reason you are using mosquito 1.4.12, it is VERY old

Comment: Thank you for your help. The issue was resolved after I switched the hash to sha512

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. I solved it by running mqtt without password protection to get it running. (`allow_anonymous true` in mosquitto.conf). Then I used `docker exec -it mqtt sh` (mqtt being my container name) to open a command shell. Then I tried to navigate to the path I entered in the mosquitto.conf file (`cd /etc/mosquitto`) . For me, the mosquitto folder wasn't there. I added a volume statement in my docker compose file to map the OS path to the docker container. (`- /etc/mosquitto/pwfile.pwd:/mosquitto/pwfile.pwd`). Stopped the container (`docker stop mqtt`). Then I removed the container (`docker container rm mqtt`). Then I started the contaner using my docker compose file (`sudo docker-compose -p mqtt up -d`). I checked the log with `docker logs mqtt`. Saw mqtt was running without errors.